# Is WD elements with NTFS format supported on Ubuntu?

Tags: windows-8, ntfs, external-hdd, support

I brought a WD Elements 1tb external hdd and I'm planning to install Ubuntu on my laptop.(not a dual boot). So I was wondering will the hdd work on Ubuntu, it's ntfs formatted.I dont want to format it again just for ubuntu. i want it to be able to work on different os platforms as well

Comment: yes ntfs is supported via ntfs-3g module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the external hard drive with NTFS file format will work with Ubuntu file system in your laptop. However, if you plan to install Ubuntu on the same hard drive, you need to reformat it to ext4 file system.